# Mockito inOrder.verify() fails - "Wanted but not invoked ... wanted anywhere AFTER following interaction"

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, mockito

I've been given a bunch of tests to develop a simple game and I've reached a point where Mockito's `InOrder.verify()` produces the error.

> Verification in order failure. Wanted but not invoked: jumpListener.jumpPerformed( ... ) at line x. Wanted anywhere AFTER the following interaction: walkListener.walkPerformed( ... ) at line y.

The code I got looks similar to what is seen below where the relevant functions `performWalk(int x)` and `performJump(int y)` both contains other function calls in if / else logic, before and after `walkListeners.get(0).walkPerformed(x);` and `jumpListeners.get(0).jumpPerformed(y);`. I've never heard about Mockito until reaching this part and most questions seems to be asked by those producing the tests, not using them. So my question is, what exactly does `inOrder.verify()` require of the function calls?

```
order.verify(walkListener).walkPerformed(5);
order.verify(jumpListener).jumpPerformed(2);
```

Can there be other function calls going off between these two statements, say a boolean function checking the argument value interval?

```
public interface WalkListener extends EventListener {
    public void walkPerformed(int x);
}

public interface JumpListener extends EventListener {
    public void jumpPerformed(int y);
}

public class Game {
    private Vector<WalkListener> walkListeners;
    private Vector<JumpListener> jumpListeners;

    public void addWalkListener(WalkListener listener) { ... }
    public void addJumpListener(JumpListener listener) { ... }

    public void performWalk(int x) {   
        ... 
        walkListeners.get(0).walkPerformed(x);
        ...
    }
    public void performJump(int y) { 
        ...      
        jumpListeners.get(0).jumpPerformed(y);
        ... 
    }

    private class Walk implements WalkListener { ... }
    private class Jump implements JumpListener { ... }
}

public class GameTest {
    @Test
    public void finalTest() {
        Game game = new Game();
        WalkListener walkListener = mock(WalkListener.class)
        JumpListener jumpListener = mock(JumpListener.class)

        game.addWalkListener(walkListener);
        game.addJumpListener(jumpListener);

        game.performWalk(5);
        game.performJump(2);

        InOrder order = inOrder(walkListener, jumpListener);
        order.verify(walkListener).walkPerformed(5);
        order.verify(jumpListener).jumpPerformed(2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Verify that xxPerformed are being called in the order you anticipate, with the values you told Mockito. GL!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So this is the relevant bit:

```
InOrder order = inOrder(walkListener, jumpListener);
order.verify(walkListener).walkPerformed(5);
order.verify(jumpListener).jumpPerformed(2);
```

It verifies that

1. jumpListener is called after walkListener (the case you're failing, since you apparently don't call jumpListener at all),
2. walkListener.walkPerformed() is called with argument `5` and
3. jumpListener.jumpPerformed() is called with argument `2`

> Can there be other function calls going off between these two statements, say a boolean function checking the argument value interval?

Sure.

See example:

```
class Foo {
    public void foo() {}
    public void bar() {}
    public void baz() {}
}

@Test
public void testFoo() {

    Foo mock = mock(Foo.class);
    mock.foo(); //1st
    mock.bar(); //2nd
    mock.baz(); //3rd

    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mock);

    inOrder.verify(mock).foo(); //1st
    inOrder.verify(mock).baz(); //3rd (last method)

    //passes because there are no more interactions after last method:
    inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();

}
```

Test passes, as after `baz()` call there were no more method calls. It doesn't matter that `bar()` call was in between as that was not part of verification.

Same is the case with two classes:

```
class Foo {
    public void foo() {}
    public void bar() {}
}

class Bar {
    public void foo() {}
}

@Test
public void testFoo() {

    Foo mock = mock(Foo.class);
    Bar mock2 = mock(Bar.class);
    mock.foo(); //1st
    mock.bar(); //2nd
    mock2.foo(); //3rd

    InOrder inOrder = inOrder(mock, mock2);

    inOrder.verify(mock).foo(); //1st
    inOrder.verify(mock2).foo(); //3rd (last method)

    //passes because there are no more interactions after last method:
    inOrder.verifyNoMoreInteractions();
}
```

Test again passes, as the second method call was not part of verification.

If you'd have wanted the test to fail on non-specified methods calls, you'd need to add for example `Mockito.verifyNoMoreInteractions(mock);` at the end of the test.

Comment: Great! This reduced the amount of troubleshooting by alot. It appears one of my arguments did not match the desired state.